# How to make a TikZ style behave differently depending on whether an argument is passed to it

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

While I know how to give a style a default value, so that the argument becomes optional, what I can't figure out is how to make the behavior of the style *different* depending on whether the argument is given at all. To illustrate what I mean, here's a rather contrived example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\tikzstyle{quux} = [draw=red,blue,thick]

\node[quux] (a) {A};
\node[quux,right=of a] (b) {B};
\node[quux,right=of b] (c) {C};
\node[quux,right=of c] (d) {D};
\node[quux,right=of d] (e) {E};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image: results]

Unfortunately, there's a lot of redundancy in this code. Now, for such a simple example, it doesn't especially matter. But there are other instances where eliminating this redundancy would be helpful. As we can see, for all nodes but `(a)`, we have the code `right=of (x)`, as obviously the position of the first node doesn't need to be placed relative to another, and in fact can't be. What I would like is something like the following:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\tikzstyle{quux} = [draw=red,blue,thick,if argument present={right=of #1}]

\node[quux]   (a) {A};
\node[quux=a] (b) {B};
\node[quux=b] (c) {C};
\node[quux=c] (d) {D};
\node[quux=d] (e) {E};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: `\tikzstyle{}` is deprecated.

Comment: You can use `.code` rather than `.style`. Then you could test if the value was some default one (e.g. `NOVALUEPASSED` and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Incidentally, I know this is just an example, but you do know it is reinventing a wheel which has been invented at least twice by default PGF/Ti*k*Z alone, right?

Comment: @cfr I suppose I don't. What were you referring to in particular?

Comment: The `chains` library does basically this. It is now considered deprecated and is being replaced, I think, by the `graphs` syntax. But `chains` is still very useful and a lot more straightforward to grasp. For me anyway.

Comment: So you can say, e.g., `start chain=main going right` and then `\node [on chain] ...`. And so on. Each node is placed relative to the last ... in a chain. And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.append code` and check inside if the parameter is empty, for example using `\ifx`, and if not set `right of=#1` using `pgfkeysalso` like this :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  quux/.style={blue,draw=red,thick},
  quux/.append code={\ifx\\#1\\\else\pgfkeysalso{right of=#1}\fi},
  quux/.default={}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[quux] (a) {A};
    \node[quux=a] (b) {B};
    \node[quux=b] (c) {C};
    \node[quux=c] (d) {D};
    \node[quux=d] (e) {E};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]